# iGoogle doesn't use new theme in Opera

Tags: igoogle, opera

Google implemented a new design for nearly all websites, including iGoogle. It now uses blue and red buttons, and the the classic iGoogle theme has grey title bars for the widgets. This new design shows up in all the browsers I've tried (IE9, FireFox 7 and 8, Chrome 15) on both my home computer and my work computer, except in Opera (10.5 through 11.6).

On Opera the search buttons are the standard browser form elements, the widget title bars are still blue and the widget menu on the left is still expanded instead of minimized. Does this only happen to me, or does Google use different styling just for Opera browsers? How can I get the new theme in Opera?

**EDIT**: I actually found a way to get the new design. You can identify Opera as FireFox or IE by navigating to iGoogle and performing the following actions in Opera: Opera->Settings->Quick preferences->Edit site preferences->Network->Browser identification. If you set this dropdown to 'Firefox', everything will be fine. Incidentally, this solution also fixed my problems with Google Calendar in Opera.

This all seems rather childish to me. I remember Microsoft doing this sort of thing for their MSN website. I though Google would be better than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Google is using different styling with Opera. I was able to reproduce your problem on Windows 7 with Opera 11.52.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Please see my edit for a workaround.